# Capturing Bluetooth Headset longpress event in android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to launch my Main activity when the Bluetooth button is longpressed, much like how Google Voice launches when you longpress the BT button but I can't seem to find the right action to trigger it.

my current code:

```
public class LaunchReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.d("HERE", action);
    }
}
```

In manifest:

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.app.LaunchReceiver"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.headset.action.VENDOR_SPECIFIC_HEADSET_EVENT" />
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VOICE_COMMAND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.WEB_SEARCH" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Right now, with the above code, the only action that displays is CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED, but that also happens when you turn on/off the headset. I've been trying the other answers in stackoverflow with no success.

--- edit --- the solution to this was to:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.LaunchActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VOICE_COMMAND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and disable S voice in application manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my understanding from bluedroid and bluetooth app(packages/apps/bluetooth) in android

Whenever bluetooth button in headset is pressed, it sends AT+BVRA command(check bluetooth hfp spec 1.5/1.6), this command expects phone to launch voice recognition

bluedroid source code
btif/src/btif_hf.c->BTA_AG_AT_BVRA_EVT calls BTHF_VR_STATE_STARTED

which gets translated to

/packages/apps/Bluetooth/+/android-4.4.2_r1/src/com/android/bluetooth/hfp/HeadsetStateMachine.java

processVrEvent->startActivity(sVoiceCommandIntent);
where sVoiceCommandIntent is ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND

so no intent is broadcasted for voice recognition .

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but from what I understand in HeadsetStateMachine.java. It starts an activity with an intent android.intent.action.VOICE_COMMAND. With that in mind, I tried to add an intent filter in the Launcher activity in my Manifest and tried to see if the longpress will launch the activity. But so far the activity is not launch. Forgive me if I'm wrong since I'm quite new with handling bluetooth

Comment: it seems disabling S Voice does the trick. thanks for all the help ashish!

Comment: @kiirohana s Voice means SCO voice ?

Comment: ah I was testing it in a Samsung phone so it had S Voice installed. So I just disabled S Voice for now.